# How to load cystalreports with out error in wpf using c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, crystal-reports-2010

How to load crystal reports in wpf,
below the am using,but it does not work,showing error as "load report failed"

```
     private void Window_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     { 
        ReportDocument orpt = new ReportDocument();
        DataSet ds=new DataSet();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT [Doctor_Name],[Qualification],[Specialization],[Hospital_Clinic_Name]", con);
        adp.Fill(ds);
        orpt.Load(Server.MapPath("~CrystalReport1.rpt"));
        orpt.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[0]);
        crystalReportsViewer1.ViewerCore.ReportSource = orpt;
      }
```

Comment: I suspect exception occurs at `orpt.Load(...)` line, right? Make sure what `Server.MapPath(...)` returns correct path and this file is exists. Maybe you have to use slash: `"~/CrystalReport1.rpt"` ?

Comment: @Sinatr: THen also shows as "Load Report Failed"